# boto3 textract start_document_text_detection doesn't accept folders for input files on s3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-textract

I've written a lambda to extract text from image files stored in s3. The lambda is triggered by new objects. The images are stored in folders.
When I test on files stored on the root of my S3 bucket, everything works fine. When I use a folder, things break.

When the documentLocation looks like this:

```
{'S3Object': {'Bucket': 'extractbucket', 'Name': 'img024.jpg'}}
```

everything works.

When it looks like this:

```
`{'S3Object': {'Bucket': 'extractbucket', 'Name': 'afold/img024.jpg'}}`
```

I get **InvalidParameterException**

**Steps to reproduce**

Here's my lambda function (Python3.8, region:us-east-2):

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    bucket="extractbucket"
    client = boto3.client('textract')
    jobFile = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    #process using S3 object
    docLoc = {
        "S3Object":{
            "Bucket": bucket,
            "Name": jobFile
        }
    }
    response = client.start_document_text_detection(
        DocumentLocation=docLoc,
        JobTag=jobFile,
        NotificationChannel={
            "RoleArn":"arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/Textract_demo_sns",
            "SNSTopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:xxxxx:TxtExtractComplete"
        }
    )
      return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps("sent filejobID:" + jobFile + " to queue")
    }
```

I test this using an S3 trigger test, putting the filename in the object/key. When I test with root files, it all works, when I test with files in a folder, things break. The break as below:

**Debug logs**

```
InvalidParameterException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the StartDocumentTextDetection operation: Request has invalid parameters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 18, in lambda_handler
    response = client.start_document_text_detection(
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 316, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 626, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)END
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

My testing shows that `start_document_text_detection()` works fine with objects in subdirectories.

I suspect that the `Key` contains URL-like characters rather than a pure slash. You can test this by printing the value of `jobFile` and looking in the logs to view the value.

Here is code that will avoid this problem:

```py
bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])
```

You will also need to `import urllib`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've tried this, but the same problem still exists. I had been printing jobFile, and DocLoc, but it looks like an ordinary slash (and indeed, that's what I'm typing into the test script) (and I had tested with one copied from a print(ed) sns response). I've also checked my IAM role, and I'm just using the generic S3 role, so no limits there either.

Comment: I took your code and ran it with hard-coded values for `Bucket` and `Name`. I only supplied `DocumentLocation` and `JobName` to make it easier to test. Try that yourself (removing the Notification) to see if you still get the same error.

Comment: aha! now we're onto something. The issue seems to be with JobTag and the key. I had assumed that as JobTag accepted a string, that it would accept the key easily. It doesn't seem to be quite this easy I'm afraid. I was hoping to use jobtag, to pass information that I could pickup after the textract was done, without storing it separately in a db

Comment: Glad you figured it out! :)

Answer (score 4):

The JobTag identifier doesn't accept spaces or symbols, including '/'.

So when adding a file with a folder, and assigning the key to JobTag, JobTag senses a slash, and returns the invalid parameter error.

**Resolution:** Remove/replace slashes in the jobtag using python [replace](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-replace/)